# /ZW can't coexist with precompiled Header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I created a Windows Store dll application with VS2015, when enabling /ZW (Consume Windows Runtime Extension), and at the same time, C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers -> Precompiled Header is set to "Use (/Yu)", and then the below error will happen:

dllmain.cpp(1): fatal error C1852: 'x64\Release\XXXXXX.pch' is not a valid precompiled header file

When /ZW is disabled, and then this issue will have gone.

Why does this constraint exist?

Comment: As I know there is no such constraint. Did you rebuild your project after setting up flags?

Comment: I am sure I have rebuild it twice, both failed until I disabled /ZW.

Comment: Have you set "Create" for precompiled header .cpp file? When enabling precompiled header all translation units except for precompiled header should have "Use" option, but translation unit for precompiled header should have "Create" option.

Comment: /ZW can be applied to each individual source file in a project.  But a PCH requires everybody to agree.  Anything named dllmain.cpp is somewhat likely to have different settings :)  Right-click the file > Properties.